# Changing between Views in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, view

I am making my first iOS application, it is for the iPad. It is a memorization game. It has cover page with a couple of options and depending on the option you choose it sends you different page/view. Throughout the application, the user will be traveling through different pages/views. The entire interface for the application will be custom made, so i want have the navigation bars or anything.  I am using xCode 3.2.5. I have created the views in the interface builder. And I have attached the cover page to the app, so after the splash page it appears.

How do I go about switching between views?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Edit 1:

Here is some code that I think is pertinent

This is the AppDelegate.m file, I left out the methods I did not edit

```
@synthesize coverController=_coverController;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.
cover *aCoverController = [[cover alloc] initWithNibName:@"cover" bundle:nil];
self.coverController = aCoverController;
// Or, instead of the line above:
// [self setcover:aCoverController];
[aCoverController release];

self.window.rootViewController = self.coverController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {

[managedObjectContext_ release];
[managedObjectModel_ release];
[persistentStoreCoordinator_ release];
[_coverController release];

[window release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. 1stly can you be a little more clearer about what you want.

From what I got was, you are not looking to navigate in/out of controllers, you just have few views prepared for your RootViewController, and then you want to switch between them.

Navigation controller is used when you have a sequential flow of views, as in moving from view1 'leads to' view2, and so on. eg- a contactsBook-->contactDetails-->editContact--> so on ..

But it feels, in your case, the views/pages are separate and have no connection whatsoever, so there wont be any sequential flow, but a random flow of say view1-->view5-->view2--> ..

If that is the case, if you have already build the views, you just need to connect each of them with their parentController(coverController in your case).

Simplest way would be - lets say you have 3 views, view1 view2 view3, each having 1 or more buttons to switch b/w views. 
1 way would be to have a reference of the coverController, in each of the views. There are more elegant methods possible, but this 1 will be the easiest to understand and implement.

So, in view1.h(add these) :

```
import "cover.h"

@class cover;

@interface view1 : UIView {

cover *coverController;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign)cover *coverController;

@end
```

And in cover.h, add

```
import "view1.h"

@class view1;

@interface cover : UIViewController{

 IBOutlet view1 *firstView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet view1 *firstView;

@end
```

Finally in cover.m, add

```
@implementation cover

@synthesize view1;
```

and in 'viewDidLoad' method in cover.m, add 2 lines

```
self.view1.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024); //set whatever frame you want

self.view1.coverController = self;   //concept of reference-paring
```

And done.

in the view1ButtonPressed method of view1 -

```
-(IBAction)view1ButtonPressed{

 // remove the current view from the superview

 [self removeFromSuperView];

 //go to superView, to load anotherview

 [coverController view1ButtonWasPressed];

}
```

in cover.m :

```
-(void)view1ButtonWasPressed{

 //after doing the same process for view2

 [self.view addSubview:view2];
}
```

If you have made the correct connections, in you nib files, you ll achieve what you set out to do.

Concept is simple, what we are doing is - on click on the button, we remove the current view from superview, go to the super view itself(which is the controller's view only), and add as a subview some other view of our choice.

There is only 1 controller, and many views, and we are switching in b/w those views.

Comment: Thank you, that worked exactly like I wanted it to. Sorry about not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a navigation controller, it's the simplest way of structuring an app with multiple views. There's nothing that says you have to show the navigation bar and you can create custom buttons which push and pop views on and off of the stack.

I've been playing with different ways of doing this and it's just not worth the effort. I strongly recommend the navigation controller.

[This tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/) helped me get my head round it, but try googling to find what works best for you.

Comment: This is kinda what I want. I have buttons on my views that are in the middle of the view , how would I say if that button is clicked move to this views with the UINavigationController?

Comment: MyViewController *aViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]
            initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:NO];
  [aViewController release];

Comment: I tried that. I did not work. I tried placing it in the sender method that was connected in my enter button `-(IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender
{
 cover *coverController = [[cover alloc]
         initWithNibName:@"cover" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:coverController animated:NO]; [coverController release];}` I tried placing it in the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView` method where i replaced `self.navigationController` with Enter which is the name of the button

Comment: "I did not work [sic]" does not help anyone. What doesn't work about it? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Sorry about that. It does not give any error messages or warning. It builds and runs. When I click on the enter button, nothing happens it does not go to next view